# php form undefined vairable

Tags: php, mysqli

Could some one help me here (newbie alert) Im putting together a login/register/admin page.

I have no idea why I've gotten undefined variables when I think I've defined them on this specific page.

> Notice: Undefined variable: fname in F:\Uni\log-on\mysql-project-users-add.php on line 34
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: insert in F:\Uni\log-on\mysql-project-users-add.php on line 42

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'tim_williams';
$pass = 'baroness';
$db  = 'php_db05';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if(!$link) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $fname     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fname']);
  $lname     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lname']);
  $email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
  $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password1']);
  $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password2']);
  if($password1 != $password2) {
    echo "Error : Passwords must match each other";
  }else{
    $password = sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password1']));
    $username  = strtolower($fname.substr($lname,0,1));
    $dateTime   = date('Y-m-d g:i:s',time());
  }
}





if ($fname && $lname && $email && $password && $username && $dateTime) {
    $qry  =  "INSERT INTO registeredusers (UserID, UserName, FirstName,  Surname, EmailAddress, Password, LastLogin)
              VALUES ('','$username','$fname', '$lname', '$email',  '$password','$dateTime')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($link, $qry);

}


if($insert) {
  header("Location: mysql-project-users-login.php");
  exit;
}

mysqli_close($link);


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/layout.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New User Registration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="holder">

      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="mysql-project-users-login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="mysql-project-users-add.php">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="pageheading">
          <h1>Register</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="contentleft">
          <h2>Welcome to my site</h2><br />
          <h6>Please register an account with us to access main content and more.</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="contentright">
          <form class="registerform" action="" method="post">
            <input class="styletxtfield" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value=""><input class="styletxtfield forminput" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value=""><br /><br />
            <input class="styletxtfield" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" value=""><br /><br />
            <input class="styletxtfield" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password" value=""><input class="styletxtfield forminput" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" value=""><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `echo $_POST['submit']` give you? (Before the `if` condition.)

Comment: Just get rid of all this `if ($fname && $lname && $email && $password && $username && $dateTime) {` and check if any are `!empty()` under your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}`.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: This isn't for a live site or is live already I hope?

Comment: Instead of using `if ($fname && $lname && && &&...` define criteria, which your input data have to fulfill (for example `$fname!==''`), and kick the useless checks like the one for `$dateTime`.

Comment: no it's not live, simply trying to learn php, this is me trying to learn the ropes

Comment: You really shouldn't use [SHA1 password hashes](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, when you do not sent form, which is when you first time go into your page, then you do not have anywhere initialized those variables. You must add your if command:

```
if ($fname && $lname && $email && $password && $username && $dateTime) {
...
}
```

inside this IF:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: That whole `if ($fname && $lname && $email && $password && $username && $dateTime) {` is utterly useless. They need to check for emptyness inside the submit conditional.

Comment: `if($insert) { ... }` (line 42ff) should be moved as well.

Comment: Yes, you both are right